# How to remove github pages CNAME while I cannot access the repository anymore

Tags: github-pages

1. I have an old github pages repository pointing to a domain purchased at namecheap
2. Suddenly this github account was suspended and i cannot access the github pages repository anmore
3. I want to make that domain pointing to another github pages repository but failed to, it complains that it was taken already - even I delete all entries in namedcheap advanced dns settings.

Any idea how to fix such issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to submit a ticket to GitHub Support https://support.github.com/request.

Here is the [help page](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-support/submitting-a-ticket)